Vuetify 3 autocomplete not closing the dropdown when selecting an option
I am building an autocomplete with Vue3, TS and Vuetify 3. I have a custom-made dropdown with options, and I am able to select the options, navigate to the selected option when clicked, and to show in the input of the autocomplete the option I have choose, but I can't figure out how to close the dropdown menu whenever I select one of the options. Here is my .vue component:
<template>
  <div>
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="search"
      class="autocomplete"
      :active="false"
      :hide-details="true"
      :items="activities"
      no-data-text="No hay"
      density="comfortable"
      placeholder="Buscar"
      item-props
      :prepend-inner-icon="mdiMagnify"
      variant="solo"
      auto-select-first
      rounded
      clearable
      color="transparent"
    >
      <template #chip="{ item }">
        <p>{{ item?.title }}</p>
      </template>
      <template #item="{ item }">
        <NuxtLink
          :to="`/activity/${item.raw.link}`"
          @click="activitySelected(item)"
        >
          <div class="element-dropdown" :class="{ 'selected': item.raw?.title === selectedActivity?.title}">
            <img :src="`/svg/categories/${item.raw.category}.svg`" alt="">
            <div>
              <p class="title">
                {{ item.raw.title }}
              </p>
              <p class="subtitle">
                {{ item.raw.location }}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </NuxtLink>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { mdiMagnify } from '@mdi/js'
import type { RealActivity } from '~/types/data_model'
const { default: activities } = await import(
  '~/assets/data/real-activities.json'
)

const selectedActivity = ref<RealActivity | null>(null)
const search = ref<null | string>(null)

function activitySelected (a: RealActivity) {
  selectedActivity.value = a
  search.value = a.title
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .autocomplete {
    @apply w-[300px];
  }
  .selected {
    background-color: $medium-gray !important;
  }
.element-dropdown {
  @apply flex items-center cursor-pointer p-2;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $light-gray;
  }
  img {
    @apply w-7 h-7 mr-2;
  }
  p {
    &.title {
      @apply text-lg -mb-1;
      font-family: $regular;
    }
    &.subtitle {
      @apply text-base -mt-1;
      color: $price-color;
    }
  }
}
</style>

For completeness, this is the data model used:
export interface RealActivity {
    link: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    title: string;
    location: string;
    category: string;
    priceEuros: number;
    min: number;
    max: number;
    cardPhoto: string;
    mainPhoto?: string;
    mainVideo?: string;
    photos: string[];
    smallDescription: string;
    special: string;
    activityAbout: string;
    timeSlots: string[];
    details: {
        languages: string[];
        duration: string;
        included: string[];
        notIncluded: string[];
        tips: string[];
        whenBook?: string;
    };
}

Thanks in advance!
I have tried to link a ref() in the v-model of the autocomplete with the options, did not work. I have tried to separate them, and that way at least I can show the title of the item selected, but I can't get the dropdown to close when I select an option.
Another problem with the current approach, I can select an item from the list, and it will show the title in the autocomplete, but It won't indeed change the filter or the options shown. Indeed, you can start writing more and it will act like the title shown does not exist

v-autocomplete takes the same menu-props as v-menu and so we can specify the option close-on-content-click to get this behavior!
    <v-autocomplete
       ...,
       :menu-props="{closeOnContentClick:true}"
    >

